# Download file using PHP and header - works only with "die" in the end

Tags: php, download, header, gzip

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

The code below is working only when I'm adding "die" in the end. Without "die" I'm receiving broken gzip file...

```
$file = $this->connection->result_body;
$fileName = "test.gz";
header("X-Frame-Options: sameorigin");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
header("Content-Type: application/x-gzip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: '. strlen($file));
echo $file;die;
```

Comment: There must be something wrong in your later script and that is the reason the execution of the script stops there itself.

Comment: please provide your further part of the script.

Comment: Are you sure nothing is ouput'ed afer your last line ? A single space could mess up your gz file.

Comment: Thank you guys very much! That's right, I had var_dump in the end of a different function which was calling this function - that was the issue.